# Как сохранять значение в базу данных? telebot, sqlite3

Tags: python, база-данных, telebot, sqlite3

У меня есть два файла, один с базой данных, другой основной. В основном файле есть две функции которые отвечают за изменение переменной attempts. Но если я буду использовать вот этот код для сохранения в базу данных attempts:

```
    def set_attempts(self, attempts):
        self.cursor.execute('''INSERT INTO users (attempts) VALUES (?)''', (attempts,))
        return self.conn.commit()w
```

P.S
То ничего не обновляется в базе данных. До и после вызова функции записи базы данных я делал проверку с помощью `print(get_init_storage(message.from_user.id))` которое выводит данные из БД. Вот код функции:

```
    def get_init_storage(self, user_id):
        result = self.conn.execute('''SELECT id,user_id,username, random_num,dev_mode_on, attempts, rand_one, rand_two FROM users WHERE user_id=?''', (user_id,)).fetchone()
        return result
```

Также в файле с БД, в функции сохранения в бд attempts, ставил `print(attempts)`, выводило значение которое я написал, но при выводе `get_init_storage(message.from_user.id)` Оставалось то же значение, а в программе `SqliteStudio` создавался новый профиль с user_id, user_name значением NULL, но с изменениями попыток какие я ставил:

[image]

Вот код сохранения переменной attempts в основном файле:

```
<@bot.message_handler(commands=['setattempts'])
def set_attempts(message):

    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Введите новое кол-во попыток:')
    bot.register_next_step_handler(message, set_attempts_global)

def set_attempts_global(message):

    user_guess = message.text

    if not user_guess.isdigit():
        msg = bot.reply_to(message, '❌Ошибка!❌\nВведите числo, а не буквы!')
        bot.register_next_step_handler(msg, set_attempts_global)
        return

    if int(user_guess) != 0:
        global attempts_default
        attempts = int(user_guess)
        attempts = BotDB.set_attempts(attempts) # не работает
        BotDB.set_attempts(attempts) # не работает
        attempts_default = attempts
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, f'✅Попытки успешно изменены✅\nНовое кол-во попыток: {attempts}')
        print('------------------------------------')
        print('attempts updated')
        print(BotDB.get_data_storage(message.from_user.id))
        print('------------------------------------')
    else:
        print('------------------------------------')
        print('attempts loose update')
        print(BotDB.get_data_storage(message.from_user.id))
        print('------------------------------------')
        msg = bot.reply_to(message, '❌Ошибка!❌\nНельзя поставить число 0!')
        bot.register_next_step_handler(msg, set_attempts_global)
        return>
```

Структура таблицы:
[image]

Использую модули `telebot`, `sqlite3`. Версия python: `python 3.12`

Comment: Ответ на предыдущий вопрос, вам не помог?

Comment: @Oopss не совсем. У меня просто переменные range, attempts, записываются не в одну строку, а в разные. Например в боте я пишу 'изменить кол-во попыток' и я ввожу число. С range также, только там два числа записываются через запятую, например 1, 200 с модулем `re`. Возможно у меня получиться сделать, если из `get_init_storage()` я смогу брать значение которое мне нужно, потому что, по какой то причине не работает запись в БД, если я для каждой переменной напишу функцию похожую на `get_init_storage()` только с 1 параметром, например attempts.

Comment: Что значит "ничего не работает"? Опишите **прямо в вопросе** что это значит: выходит ошибка? (какая ошибка - напишите прямо в вопросе) таблица в БД не обновляется? (как вы это проверяете?) какие надписи ваш скрипт выводит, какие нет (какая ветка кода срабатывает)?

Comment: Да, и покажите структуру таблицы `users`, там реально одно поле в ней `attempts`? Выглядит очень странно, что вы дописываете в таблицу значения, не имеющие никакой привязки к пользователю и т.д.

Comment: @CrazyElf я понял ошибку, я не имею привязки к пользователю. Из-за этого за место изменения попыток создается еще профиль с user_id, username NULL значением но с измененными попытками. Как мне сделать такую привязку к пользователю? я должен делать проверику есть ли пользователь в таблице? у меня тоже есть такая функция.

Comment: @CrazyElf я отредактировал вопрос

Comment: @Nqweqweqwe Ответ на предыдущий вопрос, не является ответом, я его удаляю?

Comment: @Oppss он частично правильный, щас отмечу за решенный, ведь мне надо было как раз сделать `get_init_storage()` в БД и тд.

Comment: @Nqweqweqwe Ну вам нужно `UPDATE` вместо `INSERT` использовать, если запись для данного пользователя уже есть в таблице.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В зависимости от поставленной задачи, если стоит задача сохранять все изменения, для проведения анализа и обработки статистики, рекорды, динамика набора очков, то нужно добавить еще одно поле "дата время" и каждый раз сохранять все (измененные и не измененные) значения полей в базу данных. (+ статистика; - объем базы) 
Если требуется только текущие значения можно через:

```
def update_storage(username, attempts):
    # Здесь можно сделать через try except
    # Функция для изменения значения по одному, если загрузка массовая не следует каждый раз откр и закр базу
    con = sqlite3.connect('dbusers.db')
    cur = con.cursor()
    cur.execute(''' UPDATE users SET attempts=? WHERE username=? ''', (attempts, username ))
    con.commit()
    con.close()
    return 0
```

изменять текущие значения. (- никакой истории)

Comment: Все записывается, а как мне брать информацию о попытках из `get_init_storage()`? Создать отдельные функции с `SELECT` где и выбирать эти попытки и диапазон?

Comment: информацию о попытках  конкретного пользователя или всю базу, или другое условие выбора?, да через SELECT

Comment: Сейчас я сделал для каждого значения функцию с `SELECT` и теперь выдает ошибку `Incorrect number of bindings supplied. The current statement uses 1, and there are 2 supplied.`  когда пытаюсь вывести значение из БД с помощью `SELECT attempts FROM users WHERE user_id=?''', (attempts, user_id)`. И такое происходит только с attempts, letter_a, letter_b при старте игры в боте
P.S.
вызываю функцию командой `BotDB.get_attempts(us_id, attempts)`

Comment: Запрос не верный, чтобы получить attempts  пользователя с user_id, запрос такой ,  ` '''SELECT attempts FROM users WHERE user_id=? ''', (user_id,) `